# iPhone 11 plays random music without prompting, what's going on?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

My wife's iPhone 11 running iOS 13.3.1 seems to randomly start playing stuff from the music app. We don't have Pandora or anything like it on there. The music seems to play in random situations; I haven't been able to isolate what's going on. We restarted, turned off the handoff in settings, I turned off bluetooth. Whether headphones are connected doesn't seem to matter.

I looked up the phenomenon on the 'net and found some vague answers, but there's simply not a lot of helpful information. Anyone else see anything like this?

Comment: If you open the calculator app, does the iPhone run any calculations while sitting unlocked on the table?

Comment: haven't tried that, will do

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect one of two things:

(a) you're accidentially triggering "Hey Siri"

or

(b) you have a hardware problem with the digitizer (i.e. the touch sensitive part of the display).

You can try disabling "Hey Siri" by opening Settings > Siri & Search and then turning off "Listen for 'Hey Siri'".

If you have a hardware problem with the touch input, it will probably need to go in for repair. If you some times in various apps or even on the main home screen experience that "something" moves or taps by itself, this would indicate a touch problem.

Comment: it seems to happen even absent saying hey siri, so... haven't noticed the other aspect of it with the touch